# Self derivation and tensor product with dual numbers

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, deformation-theory

Suppose $A$ is a $k$-algebra and $D$ is the ring of dual numbers. Is there any relation between $\text{Der}_k(A,A)$ and automorphism group of $A\otimes_k D$?

This question comes from the proof of Theorem 5.3 in Hartshorne's deformation theory.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: @Hoot He claimed that after taking an affine cover, getting an automorphism of $U_{ij}\times_k D$ corresponds to an element $\theta_{ij}\in H^{0}(U_{ij},T_X)$, I think my statement is just the translation of this into algebraic terms( if I have done it correctly.

Comment: I agree with your translation now! He does give a hint although I think one can be more direct in this specific situation. It seems like you want to imitate a lot of arguments from earlier in the book (but I don't see it being immediately implied by any of them). $a_1 + ta_2$ is going to go to $b_1 + tb_2$ and we must have $a_1 = b_2$. Of course one choice is to always have $b_2 = a_2$ and the rest should probably differ from this by some derivation (in $a_1$?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your specific question, you need to put together several different pieces. At the beginning of section 5, it shows that a deformation of $A$ corresponds to an extension of $k$-algebras as on page 36, say $A'$. As as $k$-vector space, $A'$ is just $A \otimes_k D$. Then use Lemma 4.5 with $R = A'$ to cook up a derivation using the identity and the automorphism as the two maps. Show that all you need is the derivation of $A$ into $A$.

Comment: Please do not sign posts.

Comment: Next edit is a lock. Please, do not sign posts.